# Place an image in the centre of remaining bottom area on iOS screen

Tags: ios, autolayout

I have placed an image on an iOS screen and in the area that remains in the bottom, I would like to place another image in the centre of that space. I could do that with Android using relative layouts. How can this be achieved in iOS auto layout?

[image: placing denko logo]

Comment: are you using storyboard?

Comment: Yes I am using the IB.

Comment: I think you will use one image which will combination of these images.

Answer (score 1):

Let the image view take up the remaining bottom space (fairly easy to do using auto layout), and then set its `contentMode` to Center.

Comment: How do you tell the image to take up the remaining space?

Comment: @SandahAung align left, right and bottom edge to container, and align top edge to the bigger image's bottom.

Answer (score 0):

This is an simple example.

Just select the `Horizontal Center in Container` after pin other required constrains.

[image]

And this is the final layout constrains:

[image]